# Could someone confirm my assumption about Btwin Original 520 Hybrid front wheel?

Tags: tire, rims, hybrid-bike

My friend has a Btwin Original 520 Hybrid Size M ([Specs](https://www.btwin.com/en/city-bikes/hybrid-bikes/3852-original-520-hybrid-bike-anthracite.html))
His bike's front wheel was stolen and I would like to replace it with something cheap (no need for the dynamo hub, for example).
I am a little confused with all the available wheel sizes and models and worried that I could buy something that won't fit.
The rear tires (factory ones) are marked 700x35c, but the specs say that 26'' is the right size for the Medium Size.

From the specs:

> WHEELS: Single-wall, machined, anodised aluminium rims. 
>   SHIMANO front hub dynamo. The quick-release system makes it easy to remove the wheels when transporting your bike.
>
> TYRES: Versatile, highly durable road/path B'Twin tyres. Dimensions: size M 26 x 1.75. Size L 700 x 1.75
>   Tyres with reflective strips offer excellent lateral visibility at night.

Also, when it comes to wheels I am guessing by the specs that I should buy 1.75'' width.
When I search for rims on amazon I am faced with all sorts of different sizing standards (32H, 36H, 700, 26'' etc). Could someone please indicate whether 26'' x 1.75'' inches are the right way to go? Can I then put 700x35c tires on it?
Are there equivalent sizes using another standard (like 36H) that are equivalent (in cae I am looking for them on amazon)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tom's answer covers it.  All you need to change is your method for locking the bike - a cable through the front wheel and a D lock through the rear wheel and frame.  Also consider getting a wheel without quick release, so old-school nuts or special security skewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend's bike will have the same size wheel on the front and back. If the rear wheel is 700c then the front wheel will be that size. The imperial equivalent of 700c would be 28 inches.

Finally, I'd suggest going to Decathlon or use their website and buying a replacement wheel with a dynamo. The price difference is minimal (less than a set of lights would cost).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The bike was bought in France, but I'm in america now. Going to Decathlon is not an option. I looked for rims with dynamos, but they're over 100$ versus 40$ for normal rims. I'll keep the suggestion in mind though.

Comment: 700C is 622 mm ISO, and sold as a 29" (29er) in MTB circles. Some 28" are also 622ISO, but not all. Confused - so is the entire industry. Refer https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html